A formula for the norm of a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$
I read in a paper that the following formula holds for a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$:
$$ \| \nabla f(x)\|^2 = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{n}{\mathcal L_n(B_n(x,\epsilon))} \int_{B_n(x,\epsilon)} \left[ \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{\|x-y \|}\right]^2 \mathcal L_n(dy).$$
Here $\mathcal L_n$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and $B_n(x,\epsilon)$ is the open ball with center $x$ and radius $\epsilon$. The paper says that we can derive the above formula using the following result, for which I know the proof:
$$  \forall \epsilon >0, \forall V\in \mathbb R^n, \quad \| V\|^2 = \frac{n}{\mathcal L_n(B_n(0,\epsilon))} \int_{B_n(0,\epsilon)}\left\langle V, \frac{u}{\|u\|} \right\rangle^2 du. $$
Although that this seems almost immediate, however, I couldn't find the proof. Thank you for your help!

By the definition of $\nabla f(x)$, we have
$$ \lim_{y \rightarrow x} \frac{|f(y)-f(x) -\langle\nabla f(x), y-x\rangle|}{ \|y - x \|} = 0.  $$
This implies
$$ \lim_{y \rightarrow x} \left| \frac{|f(y)-f(x)|}{\|y-x\|}  -  \frac{|\langle\nabla f(x), y-x \rangle|}{\| y-x \|}  \right| = 0.$$
and that (left to the OP)
$$ \lim_{y \rightarrow x} \left| \frac{|f(y)-f(x)|^2}{\|y-x\|^2}  -  \frac{|\langle\nabla f(x), y-x \rangle|^2}{\| y-x \|^2}  \right| = 0.$$
From this, we have
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon >0, \quad \|\nabla f(x) \|^2 &= \frac{n}{\mathcal L(B_n(0,\epsilon))} \int_{B_n(0,\epsilon)}  \left\langle \nabla f(x), \frac{u}{\|u\|} \right\rangle ^2 du \\
 &= \frac{n}{\mathcal L(B_n(0,\epsilon))} \int_{B_n(x,\epsilon)}  \left\langle \nabla f(x), \frac{y-x}{\|y-x\|} \right\rangle ^2 dy.
\end{align}
Given a $\delta >0$, for $\epsilon >0$ small enough, we have
$$ \forall y \in B_n(x,\epsilon),\quad \frac{|f(y)-f(x)|^2}{\|y-x\|^2} -\delta \leq \left\langle \nabla f(x), \frac{y-x}{\|y-x\|} \right\rangle ^2 \leq \frac{|f(y)-f(x)|^2}{\|y-x\|^2} +\delta $$
and so for $\epsilon$ small enough,
$$ \frac{n}{\mathcal L(B_n(0,\epsilon))} \int_{B_n(x,\epsilon)} \left[ \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{\|y-x\|}^2 \right] - n \delta  \leq\| \nabla f(x) \|^2  \leq \frac{n}{\mathcal L(B_n(0,\epsilon))} \int_{B_n(x,\epsilon)} \left[ \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{\|y-x\|}^2 \right] + n \delta $$
The conclusion follows by letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and from the arbitrariness of $\delta$.

Well, I missed this limiting argument for $\nabla f(x)$, thank you (+1)!
